# Using data-value attribute to select and echo to .php file

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have the following problem. I'm trying to load some content using AJAX and `data-value attribute` to load content in a div. I've set up the `console.log` to display the `data-value` of the link. So if you click on `Populair` the `console.log` will display `populair`. But It only shows the first item I clicked. After the first click it doesn't do anything anymore.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the data being stored somewhere. I've tried `removeData()` and emptying the `a.themafeesten` element but this removes alle the links (including text).

Here is my HTML

```
<article>
    <h1>Themafeesten</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Evolvendis peccandi assentior istam alia divitiarum laetamur acutum. Amatoriis hosti notissima arridens simulent fuisse cumanum vocet factorum, inanitate convicia prohiberet tuo, istam duxit facta, involuta numquid vos causae putent malint arbitrarer occulte maximasque, doctrinis tradere idque indicaverunt similia suspicor, excelsus liberavisse virtutum eximiae emolumenti probarentur plus. Scaevolam gravioribus multis venandi. Sanguinem consule atomis dicturam inculta exaudita, capti pecuniae intellegerem scribimus meque sensuum debitis, dubium domus. In ferae morbis dixit impedit conectitur quodsi.</p>
            <ul class="select-feestthema tk-proxima-nova">
                <li><a class="themafeest" href="#" data-value="populair">Populair</a></li>
                <li><a class="themafeest" href="#" data-value="zomer">Zomer</a></li>
                <li><a class="themafeest" href="#" data-value="winter">Winter</a></li>
                <li><a class="themafeest" href="#" data-value="terug in de tijd">Terug in de tijd</a></li>
                <li><a class="themafeest" href="#" data-value="film en tv">Film en TV</a></li>
                <li><a class="themafeest" href="#" data-value="land en regios">Land en regio's</a></li>
                <li><a class="themafeest" href="#" data-value="dinnershows">Dinnershows</a> </li>
            </ul>
    <div id="data_goes_here"></div>
</article>
```

My AJAX function:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
        $('a.themafeest').click(function() {
            var datalist = $(this).data().value;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/puurfeesten/wp-content/themes/puurfeesten-theme/change-loop.php",
                data:datalist,
                success: function(response) {
                    if ($("#data_goes_here").html() != response) {
                        $("#data_goes_here").fadeOut(200, function() {
                            $("#data_goes_here").html(response); 
                            $("#data_goes_here").fadeIn();
                            console.log(datalist);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

    });
```

`change-loop.php` only shows `hello` at this moment. I'm taking this step by step. So I would like to have the names be displayed correct. And take it from there.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you never see the selected value is because in the `change-loop.php` you `echo "hello"` and that never changes at any given time, you need to echo the data that is coming from the request. In that way you will see changes.

to add more on the comment by @ADyson :

> Or, you could make the PHP a bit more complex and at least return
>   some different test data depending on the data value sent to it.

Make the php return the value sent to it.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function()  {
        $('a.themafeest').click(function() {
            var datalist = $(this).data().value;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/puurfeesten/wp-content/themes/puurfeesten-theme/change-loop.php",
                data:{datalist:datalist},
                success: function(response) {
                            if ($("#data_goes_here").html() != response) {
                            $("#data_goes_here").fadeOut(200, function() {
                            $("#data_goes_here").html(response); 
                            $("#data_goes_here").fadeIn();
                            console.log(datalist);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

Then in change-loop.php

```
<?php

    echo $_POST['datalist'];

    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I placed the `console.log` item before the AJAX call. And added the php code to my change-loop.php. But there is nothing echo-ed. I added `session_start();` to both the HTML (top of page, before anything else) and change-loop.php but still nothing. Any idea's?

Comment: @Jay-oh did you change data in ajax to this `data:{datalist:datalist},` ?

Comment: Yeahhhh, that was it. Didn't see that was changed to. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially your code doesn't have a problem, it's the fact you're using static test data which is confusing you. If your "change_loop.php" always returns "hello", as you state, then on the second click, your statement

```
if ($("#data_goes_here").html() != response) {
```

will match "hello" with "hello" and decide not to enter the "if" block. This will cause the `fade` function not to fire, which in turn means the `console.log` will not run. This is making it look to you like nothing is happening, but that's not really true.

The simple fix is to move the `console.log` outside the ajax call, so it runs before the ajax starts. Or, you could make the PHP a bit more complex and at least return some different test data depending on the data value sent to it.

IMO however what you'd be better doing is a slightly different approach: Keep a record of the currently displayed item in a variable, and test for that every time the "click" event fires, so that you don't waste an ajax call reloading content which is already being displayed. At the moment you make the request, and then discard the content afterwards, so you're just wasting bandwidth and CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? Lets go step-by-step and understand where its breaking and why. Try the below code:

```js
$(document).ready(function()  {
        $('a.themafeest').click(function() {
            var datalist = $(this).data('value');
            console.log(datalist);
            /*$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/puurfeesten/wp-content/themes/puurfeesten-theme/change-loop.php",
                data:datalist,
                success: function(response) {
                            if ($("#data_goes_here").html() != response) {
                            $("#data_goes_here").fadeOut(200, function() {
                            $("#data_goes_here").html(response); 
                            $("#data_goes_here").fadeIn();
                            console.log(datalist);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });*/
            return false;
        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
    <h1>Themafeesten</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Evolvendis peccandi assentior istam alia divitiarum laetamur acutum. Amatoriis hosti notissima arridens simulent fuisse cumanum vocet factorum, inanitate convicia prohiberet tuo, istam duxit facta, involuta numquid vos causae putent malint arbitrarer occulte maximasque, doctrinis tradere idque indicaverunt similia suspicor, excelsus liberavisse virtutum eximiae emolumenti probarentur plus. Scaevolam gravioribus multis venandi. Sanguinem consule atomis dicturam inculta exaudita, capti pecuniae intellegerem scribimus meque sensuum debitis, dubium domus. In ferae morbis dixit impedit conectitur quodsi.</p>
            <ul class="select-feestthema tk-proxima-nova">
                <li><a class="themafeest" href="#" data-value="populair">Populair</a></li>
                <li><a class="themafeest" href="#" data-value="zomer">Zomer</a></li>
                <li><a class="themafeest" href="#" data-value="winter">Winter</a></li>
                <li><a class="themafeest" href="#" data-value="terug in de tijd">Terug in de tijd</a></li>
                <li><a class="themafeest" href="#" data-value="film en tv">Film en TV</a></li>
                <li><a class="themafeest" href="#" data-value="land en regios">Land en regio's</a></li>
                <li><a class="themafeest" href="#" data-value="dinnershows">Dinnershows</a> </li>
            </ul>
    <div id="data_goes_here"></div>
</article>
```